# NSFetchedResultsController returning wrong NSFetchedResultsChangeType

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm creating an `NSFetchedResultsController` with the following Fetch Request in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Person class])];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(sortDate))
                                                               ascending:NO]];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                             managedObjectContext:self.mainManagedObjectContext
                                                                               sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                        cacheName:nil];
controller.delegate = delegate;
NSError *error;
if (![controller performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLogError(error);
}

// Connecting up all the delegates for UITableView
```

And reloading it in `viewWillAppear` with `[self.tableView reloadData]`

A simplified `Person`

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject
/// an NSTimeInterval representing the Unix Epoch
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *sortDate;
- (void)viewed;
@end

@implementation Person
// nothing fancy or custom - no extra KVO or primitive assignments
@dynamic sortDate;
- (void)viewed {
    self.sortDate = @([NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970);
}
@end
```

My data is generated with a network request to fetch a bunch of json and convert it into `NSManagedObject`s.  The sorting looks fine.

```
1 Person A time 1437498898
2 Person B time 1437498897
3 Person C time 1437498896
```

When I adjust the `sortDate` property on `Person C` with the `-viewed` method, in the `<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>` I get a change type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` and the list is sorted like this:

```
1 Person C time 1437498900
2 Person A time 1437498898
3 Person B time 1437498897
```

When I attempt to do the same for `Person B` I instead get a change type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` and the list is sorted like this:

```
1 Person C time 1437498900
2 Person A time 1437498898
3 Person B time 1437498905
```

I can continuously update the `sortDate` for Persons `A` and `C` and they'll continue to sort correctly.  Any changes to `Person B` don't show until after the app is rebooted but then `Person B` stops updating.  Deleting and reinstalling my app (to clear CoreData) doesn't help.

If I place a `print` command in the `- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath` then I can see that `Person B`'s `sortDate` has indeed updated to the new value, which *should* cause the NSFRC to create a `Move` event instead of `Update` change type.

```
// Original Sort (logs from cellForRowAtIndexPath)
Time 1437506506 - Person B
Time 1437506490 - Person C
Time 1437506381 - Person D
Time 1437506128 - Person A

// Change Person A
Updating SortDate 1437506128 -->  1437506599
Time 1437506599 - Person A for NSFetchedResultsChangeMove

// Sorted Correctly
Time 1437506599 - Person A
Time 1437506506 - Person B
Time 1437506490 - Person C
Time 1437506381 - Person D

// Change Person B
Updating SortDate 1437506506 -->  1437506610
Time 1437506610 - Person B for NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

// Sorted Incorrectly
Time 1437506599 - Person A
Time 1437506610 - Person B
Time 1437506490 - Person C
Time 1437506381 - Person D
```

So, why is the `NSFetchedResultsController` returning the wrong `NSFetchedResultsChangeType`?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

> A move is reported when the changed attribute on the object is one of the sort descriptors used in the fetch request.
>
> An update of the object is assumed in this case, but no separate update message is sent to the delegate.
>
> An update is reported when an object’s state changes, but the changed attributes aren’t part of the sort keys.

I hope this makes it clear why you get different change types in your callback. Considering this, I would advise to clean up your fetched results controller and delegate callbacks:

- Eliminate the redundant predicate in the FRC
- Use the sort key the corresponds to the attribute name: `"sortDate"`.
- Make sure that the delegate callback method moves the table view cell to the new index path, i.e. by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` as appropriate.

Final thought: the erratic behavior you describe for one particular objects (while the others seem to work as expected) points to other possible errors, e.g in connection with updating the `sortDate` attribute.

Also, you did not explain the `keypath` variable in your fetched results controller. Maybe the grouping is contributing to the behavior you are observing.

Finally, it is possible that you are the victim of a rare malfunction of the fetched results controller delegate described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/iPhone/NSFetchedResultsChangeMoveReportedAsNSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate/) (including workaround). - Also, don't forget that if you do not need to animate the changes, you can always just invalidate the FRC and call `reloadData`.

If nothing helps I would refactor with `NSDate` instead of `NSNumber` which is anyway more intuitive.

Comment: The delegate callback doesn't receive a `Move` change type with a `newIndexPath` - it receives an `Update` change type

Comment: The last sentence in the documentation quote points to a sorting issue. - Look for mistakes when updating the object.

Comment: they all call the same `viewed` method to do this.  Why would `sortDate` be a sort key for some of the objects, but not others?

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe you are a victim of a rare malfunction.

Comment: I removed the `didChangeObject` method and performed a `[tableView reloadData]` in `controllerDidChangeContent:` and the sorting issue remains the same.

Comment: In view of my efforts, I think an up-vote is in order.

Comment: OK - last idea. It could have to do with the unorthodox use of `NSNumber`. Try refactoring by using `NSDate`.

Comment: why would the use of `NSNumber` be unorthodox?  CoreData has it as an `Integer64` type, and it's just a counter.  Also, changing it to `NSDate` would break all previous versions of the database.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is unorthodox to model dates as numbers. It would not break previous versions because you can use migration.